# Top Hits Aggregation support in Jest SearchResult

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am using below function to make aggregation query:

```
private TermsBuilder getAggregations(String[] outputFields) {

        TermsBuilder topLevelAggr = AggregationBuilders.terms("level1").field("field1").size(0);
        TermsBuilder aggr2 = AggregationBuilders.terms("level2").field("field2").size(0);
        TermsBuilder aggr3 = AggregationBuilders.terms("level3").field("field3").size(0);
        TermsBuilder aggr4 = AggregationBuilders.terms("level4").field("field4").size(0);
        TopHitsBuilder topHitsBuilder = AggregationBuilders.topHits("doc").setSize(1).addSort("fieldValue", SortOrder.DESC);

        aggr4.subAggregation(topHitsBuilder);
        aggr3.subAggregation(aggr4);
        aggr2.subAggregation(aggr3);
        topLevelAggr.subAggregation(aggr2);
        topHitsBuilder.setFetchSource(outputFields, new String[]{});

        return topLevelAggr;
    }
```

I am getting the correct aggregation query from this code, but after executing the query I am not able to extract the `top_hits` aggregation result. I am using 
`io.searchbox.core.SearchResult` class to get the query result. In this class I couldn't find any support for Top_Hits aggregation.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the top [hits aggregation java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_metrics_aggregations.html#_use_aggregation_response_12).

Here's an example from elasticsearch docs:

```
// sr is here your SearchResponse object
Terms agg = sr.getAggregations().get("agg");

// For each entry
for (Terms.Bucket entry : agg.getBuckets()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();                    // bucket key
    long docCount = entry.getDocCount();            // Doc count
    logger.info("key [{}], doc_count [{}]", key, docCount);

    // We ask for top_hits for each bucket
    TopHits topHits = entry.getAggregations().get("top");
    for (SearchHit hit : topHits.getHits().getHits()) {
        logger.info(" -> id [{}], _source [{}]", hit.getId(), hit.getSourceAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know this way, but I am using SearchResult object, instead of SearchResponse.